# definite integrals (very interesting question)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

If $u = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\left(\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x +\cos x}\right)^2\,dx$ and $v = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\left(\dfrac{\sin x +\cos x}{\cos x}\right)^2\,dx$ then find $\dfrac{v}{u}$.

please calculate!!
Ok!!I have really made around 10 different attempts for 2 hours but could not solve this interesting problem, the way its is seen looks pretty nice having the fraction just flipped , but doing it is really tough task,i wonder we have something to do with the limits otherwise it could have been solved using indefinite integral tricks,please try to attempt it , iam dying to get the answer.

Comment: Why do you say it is very interesting?  What have you tried?  Some help on formatting is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) but at least you gave us enough parentheses.  +1 for that.

Comment: That's a common "trick": "This question is very interesting so please have fun and solve it for me."

Comment: You should show some work you have done, what have you tried? otherwise it is unlikely you will get anyone here to do your work for you. Unless you do that pretty soon I foresee this question will be closed. That being said, the answer below by Jester Tran is very generous, it should suffice if you try it. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *may* be helpful,

$$\int_0^a f(x) dx  = \int_0^a f(a-x) dx.$$

Comment: @JesterTran +1 Good answer!!

Comment: @satyatech $$v = \int (tanx + 1)^2$$, that shouldn't be a hard integral.

Comment: just got solved using your tricks !!good answer!votes up to Tran please!!